# Creating Map using Intent Uri.parse("")

Tags: android

if I create Map as like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(“geo:37.827500,-122.481670”));
startActivity(i);
```

do I require same Permission in my Application or require google play service?

Answer (score 0):

You just need the permissions in the Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Internet permissions is all what you require. ACCESS_FINE_LOACATION is required if you are determing the users location using GPS. Your code will open maps application installed in your device and view the requested L&L.

I would also recommend you in using a chooser intent like below.

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose a Application"));
```

But if you are integrating `Google Maps V2` you require `Google Play Services`

This link here will help you learn
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/